# how to make rect in pygame to stop at a certain position?

Tags: python, pygame, sprite, pygame-surface

I would like my sprite to stop at a certain positio i.e. (20,100) while starting from the starting position say (100,100). Could you help me with this?

```
class Character(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    super().__init__()
    self.x=x
    self.y=y
    self.image=image
    self.rect.self.image.get_rect()
    self.rect.center=(x,y)
    #Assume initially x=100,y=100
    
    def move_character(self):
       self.x +=-1   #Telling the character to move left 
       if self.rect.center==(20,100):
              pass #This is where I want the rect to stop moving
```

Answer (score 1):

You're changing position before you check the position. This will do absolutely nothing except for changing position

Instead, you can check the position before you change position

```py
def move_character(self):
    if self.rect.center == (20, 100):
        return # Stops the function here, does not change X
    self.x -= 1
```

There are various possible solutions to this, you just got to check the position before it changes, not after. You also got to do something if it has moved past the boundary, as I did with the `return` statement.